# Como iterar un DataFrame para llenar los los parámetros de una función a traves de un bucle For

Tags: python, funciones, pandas, bucle-for, bucles

lo que intento hacer es crear una función que itere un dataframe (en este caso "Indicadores") y extrayendo los datos de cada fila, y cada columna los agregue  la formula "Rangos", para que posteriormente, esta función regrese una tupla que contenga un DataFrame por cada fila deñ DataFrame Original("Indicadores).

este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd

def Rango(Estandar, Pronostico, Meta):
    Tolerancia = float(Estandar*0.6)+float(Meta*0.2)+float(Pronostico*0.2)
    x = float(Tolerancia/3)
    n_3 = Tolerancia
    n_2 = float(Tolerancia - x)
    n_1 = (n_2 - float(n_2/3))
    n_4 = (n_3 + x)
    n_5 = (n_4 + float(n_4/3))
    rangos = pd.DataFrame({"1": [n_1],
                       "2": [n_2],
                       "3": [n_3],
                       "4": [n_4],
                       "5": [n_5]})
    return rangos


indicadores = pd.DataFrame({ "Estandar": [162, 150, 170],
                            "Pronostico": [165, 163, 150],
                            "Meta": [155, 170, 145]})
In[91]: indicadores
Out[91]: 
   Estandar  Pronostico  Meta
0       162         165   155
1       150         163   170
2       170         150   145



def rangos(Dataset):
    for index, row in indicadores.iterrows():
        x = (Rango(row['Estandar'], row['Pronostico'], row["Meta"]))
        y = (Rango(row['Estandar'], row['Pronostico'], row["Meta"]))
        z = (Rango(row['Estandar'], row['Pronostico'], row["Meta"]))
    return x,y,z

x = rangos(indicadores)

In[94]: x
Out[94]: 
(           1           2      3           4           5
 0  71.644444  107.466667  161.2  214.933333  286.577778,
            1           2      3           4           5
 0  71.644444  107.466667  161.2  214.933333  286.577778,
            1           2      3           4           5
 0  71.644444  107.466667  161.2  214.933333  286.577778)
```

El resultado debería ser diferente para cada DataFrame contenido en la tupla

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en:

```
for index, row in indicadores.iterrows():
    x = (Rango(row['Estandar'], row['Pronostico'], row["Meta"]))
    y = (Rango(row['Estandar'], row['Pronostico'], row["Meta"]))
    z = (Rango(row['Estandar'], row['Pronostico'], row["Meta"]))
```

por cada iteración del `for` (cada fila) se llama a `Rango`  tres veces con los mismos datos (misma fila), `x`, `y`, `z` son tres DataFrames idénticos por tanto en cada iteración. Al terminar el `for` las tres variables contendrán tres DataFrames iguales resultado de aplicar `Rango` a la última fila y eso es lo que retornas.

Debes llamar a `Rango` una sola vez por fila y añadir el retorno a algún contenedor, retornando al terminar el `for` dicho contenedor. Puedes usar una expresión generadora por ejemplo para obtener la tupla de DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd


def rango(estandar, pronostico, meta):
    tolerancia = estandar * 0.6 + meta * 0.2 + pronostico * 0.2
    x = tolerancia / 3
    n_3 = tolerancia
    n_2 = tolerancia - x
    n_1 = n_2 - n_2 / 3
    n_4 = n_3 + x
    n_5 = n_4 + n_4 / 3
    rangos = pd.DataFrame({"1": [n_1],
                           "2": [n_2],
                           "3": [n_3],
                           "4": [n_4],
                           "5": [n_5]}
                          )
    return rangos


def rangos(dataset):
    return tuple((rango(row['Estandar'], row['Pronostico'], row["Meta"]) 
                  for _, row in indicadores.iterrows()))


indicadores = pd.DataFrame({"Estandar": [162, 150, 170],
                            "Pronostico": [165, 163, 150],
                            "Meta": [155, 170, 145]}
                           )
x = rangos(indicadores)
```

> ```
> >>> x
>
> (           1           2      3           4           5
>  0  71.644444  107.466667  161.2  214.933333  286.577778,
>        1      2      3      4      5
>  0  69.6  104.4  156.6  208.8  278.4,
>             1           2      3           4           5
>  0  71.555556  107.333333  161.0  214.666667  286.222222)
> ```

También puedes usar una lista como contenedor mutable temporal y al final obtener una tupla a partir de la misma y retornarla:

```
def rangos(dataset):
    rangos = []
    for _, row in indicadores.iterrows():
        rangos.append(rango(row['Estandar'], row['Pronostico'], row["Meta"]))
    return tuple(rangos)
```

o hacer de `rangos` una función generadora de forma que puedas usarla para iterar con un `for-in` o construir cualquier contenedor:

```
def rangos(dataset):
    for index, row in indicadores.iterrows():
        yield rango(row['Estandar'], row['Pronostico'], row["Meta"])

x = tuple(rangos(indicadores))
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias! Me quedó muy claro todo!